# CSS HTML Div Layout Issue

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm really struggling to achieve clean code whilst trying to get the layout I want.

My current code isn't behaving with other floating divs on the page and the bottom section with text and buttons are not displaying inline and are forcing other elements out of position.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XXe4L/

I've tried various rehashings of my code but can't figure it out and am at the point where I'm starting to pull my hair out.

I'm trying to acheive a layout similar to this wireframe - https://wireframe.cc/UTHU1d.

I've copied my latest code below, minus the bottom div with text and button because I've not been able to get that anywhere near right.

**CSS:**

```
.sceneItem { clear:both; display: block; margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; }
.scenePart { display: block; width: 100%; height: 360px; float: left; }
.imgLink { margin: 0; position: relative; }
.largeImage { display: block; width: 648px; height: 360px; float: left; }
.previewImage { width: 318px; height: 180px; display: block; margin-bottom: 3px; float: left; }
.previewImage a.imgLink { }
.img { display: inline; }
```

**and HTML:**

```
<li class="sceneItem">

<div class="largeImage scenePart">
<a href="" class="imgLink" title="">
<img src="24361_01_01.jpg" class="img" alt=""></a>
</div>

<div class="previewImage scenePart">
<a href="" class="imgLink" title="">
<img src="24361_01_01.jpg" class="img" alt=""></a>
</div>

<div class="previewImage scenePart">
<a href="" class="imgLink" title="">
<img  src="24361_01_02.jpg" class="img" alt=""></a>
</div>

</li>
```

Comment: Have you considered using a pre-existing layout framework like 960.gs or skel.js? No point in reinventing the wheel, and you could create your layout in 5 minutes.

Comment: A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with proper images and explaining what's wrong with it might help.

Comment: So. What's going wrong? you're just telling us what it doesn't do. But not what it does do.

Comment: Why are you using a `li` tag without a list tag (`ul`, `ol`)? Is some HTML missing or just an oversight?

Comment: an oversight - all html/css is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that if your floats are interfering with each other, you might try creating a block formatting context for your floated images as follows:

```
.box {
    width:970px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

By doing this, any elements following will not interact with the floated images.

Note: Without the additional page elements, I can't say for sure what the problem is.